# switch within function within multiple expressions

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a logging function and it takes time, message, a date, and a case for fun. I want to replace the if/else with a switch statement.

```
var case, output
function test (time,message,date,case) {
        if(time){
            output+="Time: "+time +", ";
        }
        else{
            output+="Time: Null, ";
        };
        if(message){
            output+="Message: "+message+", ";
        }     
        else{
            output+="Message: Null, ";
        };   
        if(date){
            output+="Date: "+date+". ";
        }
        else{
            output+="Date: Null. ";
        };
        case.toLowerCase();
        if(case==="lowercase"){
            output.toLowerCase();
            case="lowercase";
        }
        else if(case==="uppercase"){
            output.toUpperCase();
            case="uppercase";
        }
        else{
            return output;
            case="regular";
        }
 return case, output;
};
```

How do I make the if/else statements into a switch statement? What will the expression be?

Comment: What've you tried? We don't write code. You won't be able to write *all* of it in one switch because their conditions are different

Comment: A switch statement is used when one variable could have many different values. You are checking several variables so you can't just make it a single switch.